# C++ pure virtual class inside class template

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a pure virtual class(DataSource) into a custom datastruct(AVLTree) that is a member of a class (dataManager); the pure virtual class has both children RealTime and Simulation however I couldn't figure out how to instantiate both of them:

AVLTree.h:

```
public:
        T& info;
        AVLnode* left;
        AVLnode* right;
        unsigned int leftHeight;
        unsigned int rightHeight;
    public:
        AVLnode(T&);
    };

    template <typename T>
    class AVLTree {
    private:
        AVLnode<T>* startNode;
    public:
        AVLTree(T&);
```

DataSource.h:

```
class DataSource {
    public: 
        virtual void readData(std::string&) = 0;
    };
}
class RealTime : public DataSource{
 ...
}

class Simulation : public DataSource{
....
}
```

DataManager.h:

```
class DataManager {
    private:
        DataStruct::AVLTree<DataSource*> dataSource;
}
```

DataManager.cpp:

```
DataManager::DataManager(Data::FileType filetype, const std::string& loc, const std::string& name):
    dataSource(filetype == Data::RealTime ? &Data::RealTime(loc + name)) : &Data::Simulation(loc+name){}
```

I've tried making it a function to determine the type that is supposed to return but still gotten the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this, or could show me some pointers?

Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT:
I have tried both of the solutions from below with:

- adding in the new keyword
- creating the factory pattern

However, I still get the warning:
*operand types are incompatible (Data::RealTime* and Data::Simulation*)*.

here is the updated code:

```
dataSource(filetype == Data::FileType::RealTime ? new Data::RealTime(loc + name) : new Data::Simulation(loc+name))
// error occured in - new Data::Realtime  : (<-here) new Data::Simulation...
```

I do not understand why I am unable to use a ternary operator.

Comment: `Data::RealTime(loc + name)` looks like a temporary object. Taking an address of a temporary is not a good idea and is not legal in C++. You probably want to allocate your objects dynamically. It is recommended to read up on smart pointers and on the factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `&Data::RealTime(loc + name)` you're attempting to take the address of a *temporary* object, one which will be destructed immediately (making that pointer worthless). In C++ you simply can't take the address of such object.

What you need to do is to create an object using `new`, as in `new Data::RealTime(loc + name)`

Don't forget the `delete` the object later.

---

With that said, a better solution is to not use "raw" non-owning pointers at all, but instead use a *smart* pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: hello!, thanks for the response. I added the new keyword into before the instantiations; however i still get the error operand types are incompatible (Data::RealTime* and Data::Simulation*). I dont understand why i cant use ternary operators for this...

Comment: @TanSaint The problem is that both paths of a ternary expression (the conditional expression you use) must be directly convertible to each other. The types `Simulation*` and `RealTime*` can both be converted to their common `DataSource*` base, but C++ doesn't allow for both branches to be converted. The simple solution to that is to cast both results to `DataSource*`. A better solution is to call a function which returns a `DataSource*`, and which does the creation using plain `if else` (this will also make your code easier to read and understand and maintain).